# vb.net Solution file module windows disappeared(Visual Studio 2013/copy and paste)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, module, solution, solution-explorer

I am not familiar with the development environment of Visual Studio, but I really need help on this problem or I cant open the file again.

It is a finished project and I copy and paste it in another file on the same hard disk of my computer, while I didnt copy the solution file but only the file with those bin, My Project, obj and etc included in it.

Then I rename the file name in the window explorer, while the .vb , .vbproj and .resx file stay in the same name as the original file did.

When I try to open the Project through the Solution file, weird things occur, all those modules windows disappeared, those design form, the .vb modules, all disappeared, and in the Solution Explorer, instead of showing the OriginalFile.vb, it shows the renameFile.vb, then I deleted the renameFile, and try to open it again, and yet, the problem is still not solved, the Solution Explorer is still showing the renameFile.vb, and I have no idea what is happening, since I really dont know how the file of Visual Studio works.

There are error messages showed on the list, it is, 
Unable to open module file 'F:\RenamedFile_Location.vb': System Error &H80070003&
from line 1 of both RenamedFile.vb and RenamedFile.Designer.vb

I tested the program in the Release/Debug file in the OriginalFile, and the program still works, but still cannot open the Solution file

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated, I dont really understand why and how does this problem occurs, so if it is not able to be solved, I am going to redo my whole project.

Comment: the solution contains references to the other files. click *Show All Files* in solution explorer and import the various files

Comment: @Plutonix thanks, seems like some of the modules are here again, but which the file for the design of the UI? I cannot find the Design module, and one more weird thing now, when I press Start to start debugging, seems like the program has roll back to an older version of my finished project? Which i didnt keep a backup for it in anywhere.

Comment: all modules has returned, thanks, but somehow my program rolls back to the older version when it is debugging, but this should be the problem of the code since I connected to references of other files, thanks again